# How can I run a PyQt application in C++?

Tags: python, c++, pyqt

I have written a python script with a QMainWindow. Now, I need to run it in a C++ process and enable them to get communication later. However, after I run the window in C++, the window always flashes for a moment and then exits.

How can I deal with the problem? Thanks a lot!

Python Script helloworld.py:

```
import sys
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("window app")
        print('created')
        self.show()

def test():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

C++:

```
#undef _DEBUG
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Py_SetPythonHome(...);
    Py_Initialize();
    if (!Py_IsInitialized()) {
        return -1;
    }

    PyRun_SimpleString("import os, sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(os.getcwd())");

    PyRun_SimpleString("import helloworld");
    PyRun_SimpleString("helloworld.test()");

    Py_Finalize();
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: I am sorry. It should be "exits"

Answer (score 0):

From python documentation

> void Py_Finalize()
>
> Undo all initializations made by Py_Initialize()
>   and subsequent use of Python/C API functions, and destroy all
>   sub-interpreters (see Py_NewInterpreter() below) that were created and
>   not yet destroyed since the last call to Py_Initialize(). Ideally,
>   this frees all memory allocated by the Python interpreter. This is a
>   no-op when called for a second time (without calling Py_Initialize()
>   again first). There is no return value; errors during finalization are
>   ignored.

So I guess you called the function that's why the behavior happens?

I suggest call `system("pause")` before `py_finalize`

Comment: I have tried to comment `Py_Finalize()`, but it doesn't help. If the `test()` does not exit, the code will not go to `Py_Finalize()`. I guess `PyRun_SimpleString` automatically ran the method `exit()` of QMainWindow.